# Reflection of a Gaussian Beam

Tags: visible-light, reflection, laser

When a diverging Gaussian beam reflects off a surface does it continue to diverge, and if so, in what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the surface is a perfect specular reflector, the divergence of the beam will be unchanged (it will continue to diverge). If the surface is not perfect, the answer could be "anything".

Comment: What if the surface is specular but non-planar (i.e. it has some degree of curvature)?

Comment: I should have been explicit - for the purpose of the above answer, I consider a curved surface "imperfect". In principle it is possible, with a appropriately curved surface, to "somewhat refocus" a diverging beam. Simple ray tracing should tell you how.